# running multiple instances of tomcat on Centos

Tags: tomcat, centos

On Centos 6.4, I am trying to run multiple instances of tomcat based on this tutorial:
[http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/188102/](http://web.archive.org/web/20141004194803/http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/188102/)

in order to illustrate the problem, I copy the default configuration to a new instance `/srv/tomcat/solr` keeping the same default port values (and I stop the default service /etc/init.d/tomcat6 to avoid port conflicts), as follows:

```
sudo su -

yum install tomcat6

name=solr

mkdir -p /srv/tomcat/${name}/logs
mkdir /srv/tomcat/${name}/webapps
mkdir /srv/tomcat/${name}/work
mkdir /srv/tomcat/${name}/temp
cp -R /usr/share/tomcat6/conf/ /srv/tomcat/${name}
#rm /srv/tomcat/${name}/conf/tomcat6.conf  # this line is not in the tutorial, but adding it produces the same result
chown -R tomcat. /srv/tomcat/

ln -s /etc/init.d/tomcat6 /etc/init.d/${name}

cat >/etc/sysconfig/${name} <<EOF
CATALINA_BASE="/srv/tomcat/${name}"
CATALINA_PID="/var/run/${name}.pid"
CONNECTOR_PORT="8080"
TOMCAT_LOG="/srv/tomcat/${name}/logs/catalina.out"
EOF

# I keep the default port values at: /srv/tomcat/solr/conf/server.xml

/etc/init.d/tomcat6 stop   # to avoid port conflicts
/etc/init.d/${name} start  # i start my new instance

[root@localhost ~]# /etc/init.d/${name} start
Starting solr:                                             [  OK  ]

[root@localhost ~]# /etc/init.d/${name} status
PID file exists, but process is not running                [FAILED]

[root@localhost ~]# cat /srv/tomcat/solr/logs/catalina.out 
/usr/sbin/tomcat6: line 30: /srv/tomcat/solr/logs/catalina.out: Permission denied
```

what can be the problem?

Comment: try commenting this line chown -R tomcat. /srv/tomcat/ and then running

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking through the same tutorial now; first off, is there more information in your catalina.out that would tell us which file/files that got the Permission denied message from?

Based on what I'm seeing, it looks like tomcat attempted to startup, created the PID file, and died unexpectedly due to a permissions issue - never cleaning up the PID file.

I can only assume that you've gone through the comments at the end of the article - the third comment, for example, explains how one of the readers had to create/chown new folders under /var/log as /var/log/${i}.

A couple of ideas:

1. I see that you did a "chown -R tomcat. /srv/tomcat/" … I might add the group in there as well, something like "chown -R tomcat:tomcat /srv/tomcat/"  ( I don't know what that dot does after the user tomcat - is that a typo? )
2. Also, this line from the tutorial seems incorrect "cp -R /usr/share/tomcat6/conf/ /srv/tomcat/${i}".  The tutorial *should* make a directory for /usr/share/${i}/conf … which should contain files like server.xml, tomcat-users.xml, web.xml, context.xml.
3. You can always add some logging into the startup script, or increase the logging level within tomcat to try to get more visibility into the issue - that's one of the great perks of working with open source.  Use the force, Luke!
4. I'm a little confused about what's happening between your "ln -s" command, your "cat >/etc/sysconfig/...", and your "/etc/init.d/${name} start" command.  I don't see how the sysconfig file would get invoked (see #3 above).  I would think that instead of a "ln -s", you would need to make a copy, then put your bash variables within that copy, and finally invoke that copy.
5. If you have any wars under /srv/tomcat/${name}/webapps/, they need to also be owned by tomcat:tomcat.  Bad things can happen if you startup your tomcat instance as the root user, catch yourself, and then startup as tomcat. Those files under webapps need to be re-chowned.  On that same line, I've seen examples on the net where folks drop in a war into webapps/, owned by root, and then chown it to the tomcat user while tomcat is running.  I would consider that a bad practice.  Chown it to the tomcat user first, perhaps in a temp directory, then drop it into the webapps/ directory.